# finite fractional integral transform

Tags: integral-transforms

Several integral transforms are generalized by introducing their fractional counterparts,e.g., fractional Fourier transform is a very popular one. Similarly, their discrete versions are also fractionalized. But as per my knowledge, finite versions are not fractionalized. Is there any specific reason that we cannot fractionalize the finite integral transform?